# Preloading an Array into Core Data

Tags: ios, arrays, core-data

0I am trying to preload core data with an array when my app first runs.  In viewDidLoad, it checks to see if core data is empty. If it is, it calls a method to load core data with an array.  My problem is that when I check the contents of core data (with Core Data Pro Readonly) the contents of core data has one item in it:  "NULL".  This is the key line that I think that loads the array into core data which is giving me the problem:

```
  newArray = [elementsArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

The core data entity is called "Elements" and has one attribute "elementName". 
This is the contents of the entire method:

```
-(void)loadElementsEntity {
NSLog(@"LOADING ELEMENTS INTO CORE DATA");

NSMutableArray *elementsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
// LOAD THE DATA INTO THE ARRAY
elementsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
              @"Wall",
              @"Floor",
              @"Ceiling",
              @"Door",
              @"Window",
              @"Roof",
              @"Electrical",
              @"",
              @"* New Element *", nil];

// LOAD THE ARRAY INTO CORE DATA: ELEMENTS ENTITY
AppDelegate *aDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [aDel managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newArray;
newArray = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Elements" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

newArray = [elementsArray objectAtIndex:0];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![moc save:&error]) {  //SAVE FAILED
    NSLog(@"YOUR SAVE FAILED! %@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"YOUR SAVE SUCCEEDED.");
}

// CHECK TO SEE IF CORE DATA WAS LOADED
NSLog(@"LISTING THE ARRAY");
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Elements" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
NSArray *testArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
NSLog(@"ELEMENTSARRAY COUNT: %d", [elementsArray count]);
NSLog(@"LOADED TESTARRAY: count = %d", [testArray count]);

}
```

Can anyone point out where I am going wrong here?

---

I've updated the save portion of the method as follows using a for statement.
But it still yields one NULL entry in core data!

Please help!

```
// LOAD THE ARRAY INTO CORE DATA ELEMENTS
AppDelegate *aDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [aDel managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newString = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Elements" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSError *error = nil;

for (NSString *elementname in elementsArray) {
    NSLog(@"NAME= %@", elementname);
    [newString setValue:elementname forKey:@"elementName"];
    if (![moc save:&error]) {  //SAVE FAILED
        NSLog(@"YOUR SAVE FAILED! %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"SAVE SUCCEEDED.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to set your moc to @"Floor" and this is not the only mistake. First try not to save it as an array.

Comment: Try NOT to save it as an array?!!  I don't follow what you mean.

Comment: Every element in the array must be a row in your Elements table. You need to iterate and save them.

Comment: I see--Thank you.  I thought you suggested I should NOT save it (elementsArray) as an array which is confusing to me.  So, I think you are saying instead I must 'iterate' the items in elementsArray instead of creating an array.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is little bit long for a comment so here is the answers.

1. Yes, you should NOT save it as an array. It saves NULL cause you're trying to save an unsupported file type. You should save strings in that array separately.

// LOAD THE ARRAY INTO CORE DATA ELEMENTS

```
AppDelegate *aDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [aDel managedObjectContext];
NSError *error = nil;

for (NSString *elementname in elementsArray) {
    NSManagedObject *element = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Elements" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    element.title = elementname; //your attribute name instead title and it must be string
}

if (![moc save:&error]) {  //SAVE FAILED
    NSLog(@"YOUR SAVE FAILED! %@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"SAVE SUCCEEDED.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
newArray = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Elements" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
```

is creating a new, empty, entity instance. Then, you immediately do:

```
newArray = [elementsArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

which replaces your reference to the new entity instance with a string. So, when the context is saved you will have one empty object in it.

What you should be doing is iterating over the contents of the `elementsArray` and creating a new entity instance on each iteration, then using the contents of the array at that index to configure the new entity instance.

---

```
for (NSString *elementName in elementsArray) {

    // create a new entity instance
    NSManagedObject *newString = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Elements" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

    // configure using 'name'
    [newString setValue:elementName forKey:@"elementName"];
}

NSError *error = nil;
NSLog(@"LOADING: %@", newString);

if (![moc save:&error]) {  //SAVE FAILED
    NSLog(@"YOUR SAVE FAILED! %@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"SAVE SUCCEEDED.");
}
```

Comment: I see now what you mean about rewriting the newArray line.  But how do i iterate over the contents of the elementsArray?  I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Ahhh, you're simply saying to use a for statement!! Gotcha, thanks!!  I thought of doing this but won't that just recreate the same entity for every item in the elementsArray?

Comment: As I feared, I still get one NULL statement when iterating (using a for loop).  See my appended code above, if you care to lend your input.

Comment: I would like to thank you very, very much for your help.  I would have thought one should save the moc within the loop every time a new elementName is introduced from the array.  Obviously I was wrong about that.  Many thanks, Sir!

Comment: Not every time. If you have lots of additions to make you should save in batches (maybe 25 at a time, maybe 50, depends on the size of the objects)